# ILLEGAL TOKEN on eval (the one done by require() )

Tags: javascript, requirejs, comments, eval

I just diffused a (draft) lib emulating OpenGL1/glu/glut in webGL.
For a few people the demo crash on the very first "require" of my lib, console saying "*Illegal Token*" ( see [distrib page](http://www-evasion.imag.fr/Membres/Fabrice.Neyret/demos/#webGL), 1st demo '[fractal](http://www-evasion.imag.fr/Membres/Fabrice.Neyret/demos/webGL/fract4.html)' for instance. )

Googling massively tell about ILLEGAL TOKEN being due to zero-width space (frequent clandestine passenger when copy-pasting), but it is not the case in my files.
So what can it be ?

Thanks !

Comment: You are inlining all your JS code directly into the HTML document and everything is in the global scope anyway - why do you insist on using RequireJS in the first place? Mixing modular and non-modular code is generally recipe for disaster.

Comment: I use require like include is used in C: I don't want to annoy users with my sub-includes, + I want to organize them in a "lib" folder (knowing that gl-matrix already use folders and require) to let the user see only his files. And I'm not suppose to pollute the global space :-) . 
Anyway require() is quite standard, and my lib is working in most machine. Or do you think that something I'm doing wrong could cause the issue at the very first require(mylib), (where eval(mylib) says 'illegal token' on some machines ) ?

Answer (score -1):

I found the bug:  backquotes (i.e. template string), for some old versions of browsers - see [ECMA-262 compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings#Browser_compatibility). Require() use eval(), and eval will badly fail if the required js file contains backquotes.

If one want to be compatible with IE, Safari, and pre-2015 versions of chrome, firefox, opera, don't use backquote :-( but keep dying with bunches of "...\n"+ per line to encapsulate multi-line strings such as shaders, help text, etc.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be RequireJS-specific, then, just general advice: older browsers don't work with ES6 because they're... old? Also, I know you're looking at me as previous version of your comment targeted me via @; I've just cast third vote, so it's +1/-2; this is my first vote here. You should not make people regret commenting on your questions by intimidating them by jumping to conclusions.

Comment: "ES6 is new": yes, but I was not aware at all that backquotes were such a recent feature, as multiline strings are so natural, and present in numerous online tuto. Once you know the (possibly young) age of each feature you are using, you have already almost solve these kind of bugs ! I guess most people are not in this category, especially beginners in JS (which I am, despite senior in other langages).

Comment: not require-js specific: true (and I don't think I claimed otherwise :-) ).
Still, plainty of people will have the problem using require-js (not even knowing it uses eval which has the problem). That's why even if we tell about eval, I guess it is ultra-important to mention require here.

Comment: BTW concerning your comment, it was not really constructive: you suggest not-to-use require but propose no alternative (accounting some list of requirement). And as a beginner in JS, receiving your sentence "Mixing modular and non-modular code is generally recipe for disaster" was kind of dry: I would have loved to understand what it means, what to take care of, possibilities, i.e. having something to learn from your comment. PS: I don't pretend to be perfect myself, anyway ;-D . cheers ;-)